# Replace the bottom layer in a toggle button

Tags: android, drawable, layer, togglebutton

I am relatively new to Android programming. I am trying to create a toggle button with an image as a background.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:textOn="@string/text_toggle_off"
    android:textOff="@string/text_toggle_on"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_off"/>
```

As the button state changes, I replace the image programatically:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        ((ToggleButton) view).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_on));
    } else {
        ((ToggleButton) view).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_off));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the base layer of the ToggleButton changes color with the state. I always want to base layer to be transparent. Is there an easy way to do this through the Java code?